# Comparing norms on $l^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider the Banach space $(l^{\infty}, \| \cdot\|_{\infty})$ and let $\| \cdot \|$ be another on $l^{\infty}$ such that $(l^{\infty}, \| \cdot \|)$ is also a Banach space. Assume that, for each $j$, the mapping $\phi_j \colon l^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi_j( (x_n)_{n \ge 1} ) = x_j$ is continuous with respect to the norm $\| \cdot \|$.

We want to show that there exists $C > 0$ such that $$\| x\| \le C \| x \|_{\infty}$$ for all $x \in l^{\infty}$.

Since $\phi_j$ is continuous with respect to $\| \cdot \|$, we have there is a constant $M_j>0$ such that $\| \phi_j(x) \| \le M_j \|x\| $ (that is, $\phi_j$ is bounded). But I have no idea to continue, only that I need to use the Closed Mapping Theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the existence of such a constant is equivalent to showing that the identity operator $I:(\ell^\infty,\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to(\ell^\infty,\|\cdot\|)$ is bounded. We may use the closed graph theorem for this, as we have Banach spaces for domain and target. Assume that $(x_n)\subset\ell^\infty$ is a sequence so that $x_n\to0$ in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, i.e. $\|x_n\|_\infty\to0$. We want to show that $x_n\to 0$ in the $\|\cdot\|$ norm and by the closed graph theorem we can assume that $x_n\to y$ in $\|\cdot\|$ for some $y\in\ell^\infty$. Let's say $y=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ and say $x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2,\dots)$.

So we have that $\|x_n-y\|\to0$, so by the assumption that those functionals are continuous we have that for any $j\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$x_n^j\to y_j$$
But $|x_n^j|\leq\sup_{j}|x_n^j|=\|x_n\|_\infty\to0$, so $x_n^j\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ and therefore $y_j=0$ for all $j$. Thus $y=0$ and we are done.